# Rails aggregating polymorphic has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

In my app, an `Account` can be owned by a `Household` or a `User`.  Users can access accounts that they own, and accounts that their household owns.  I've defined `accessible_accounts`, that gives me an array of both household and user accounts, but is there a way to get the same result as a relation, so I can chain it with further conditionals?  The order is unimportant (and indeed can be set with further chaining)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts, as: :owner

  belongs_to :household

  def accessible_accounts
    ua = accounts.to_a
    ha = []
    if household
      ha = household.accounts.to_a
    end
    (ua + ha).uniq
  end
end

class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :accounts, as: :owner
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of thoughts on this:

First, you could express the `Account` that `User` has through `Household` by adding the following to the `Accounts` model:

```
has_many :accounts, through: household
```

However, I understand that you want a `Relation` that represents the merge/union of the accounts that a user owns directly with the accounts they own through their associated household. If that's true, then I think the following method added to `User` will give you what you want:

```
def accessible_accounts
  Account.where(
    '(ownable_id = ? and ownable_type = ?) or (ownable_id = ? and ownable_type = ?)',
    id, User.to_s, household_id, Household.to_s)
end
```

I have not tested this, but I thought I'd go ahead and share it and count on feedback if I've misunderstood something.

Comment: `you want a Relation that represents the merge/union of the accounts` - correct.  I was thinking something like this would work, but I was hoping there'd be something not so close to the SQL.

Comment: So were you thinking of something like `has_many_aggregated [:accounts, :household_accounts], as: :accessible_accounts`?  You could do that, but the "write" methods would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a proper polymorphic association I think your structure would be as following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :household
  has_many :accounts, as: :ownable
end

class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :accounts, as: :ownable
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
end
```

By the way, do you have any speacial reasons for not using Devise and CanCan for authentication & authorization?

Comment: The change `ownable -> owner` doesn't change anything.
I removed the Devise statements for for clarity.

Comment: Firstly, the only change is not `owner -> ownable` . I've added related association for polymorphisism to `User` model. Secondly, if you're already using Devise any special reason for not using `CanCan` ? https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as mine, but with `owner` replaced with `ownable`.  My code already has the association.  I'm not using CanCan because I don't need it - all the authorization is simple enough for the controller to handle.